# I'm trying to correct the layout of Aqua buttons in GroupLayout, but is it even possible?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, grouplayout

I noticed if you try to use `LEADING` alignment in `GroupLayout` when one of the components is a button and the other is not a button, the components no longer line up.

If both components are buttons, you get results like this:

```
getContainerGap(button, EAST, container) -> 14
getContainerGap(another button, EAST, container) -> 14
getContainerGap(button, WEST, container) -> 14
getContainerGap(another button, WEST, container) -> 14
getContainerGap(button, SOUTH, container) -> 17
getPreferredGap(another button, button, RELATED, SOUTH, container) -> 4
getContainerGap(another button, SOUTH, container) -> 17
```

[image: result of layout when both are buttons]

If you get out a ruler, you can see that the left margin is exactly 20 pixels, so this result is correct.

If one of the components is *not* a button (usually I'm seeing this when I try to align a button to the left edge of a `JScrollPane` or similar), you get results like this:

```
getContainerGap(button, EAST, container) -> 14
getContainerGap(reference component, EAST, container) -> 20
getContainerGap(button, WEST, container) -> 14
getContainerGap(reference component, WEST, container) -> 20
getContainerGap(button, SOUTH, container) -> 17
getPreferredGap(reference component, button, RELATED, SOUTH, container) -> 7
getContainerGap(reference component, SOUTH, container) -> 20
```

[image: result of layout when one component is not a button]

Now if you get out a ruler, the left margin of the red border is exactly 20 pixels, but the button juts out an additional 6 pixels.

The `getVisualMargin` method exists to correct this, and you can see that `getContainerGap(button, EAST, container)` returns `14`, which is compensating for the 6 pixels of extra margin outside the button.

If you have more types of component to lay out, the results get progressively worse and you end up with a jagged edge all the way down the layout, since only similar components will align with each other.

I'm wondering what is going on here. Even though the `LayoutStyle` is returning the right value for the container gap, it seems like `GroupLayout` is throwing away the value and using the value from the other component, which guarantees that the layout will be wrong.

Test program source:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class ButtonVisualMarginTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonVisualMarginTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LayoutStyle.setInstance(new AquaLayoutStyle());

        JComponent reference = new JComponent() {};
        reference.setName("reference component");
        reference.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        reference.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        reference.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

//        JButton reference = new JButton("Another button");
//        reference.setName("another button");
//        reference.setFocusable(false);

        JButton button = new JButton("Text only");
        button.setName("button");
        button.setFocusable(false);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setName("container");
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(container);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        container.setLayout(layout);
        container.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 255));
        container.setOpaque(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(reference)
            .addComponent(button));

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(reference)
            .addComponent(button));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The slightly modified version of AquaLayoutStyle I'm trying to work with is [here](https://gist.github.com/trejkaz/8861831) (it was too big to include.)

Because people might be curious, here is the result of *not* using `AquaLayoutStyle`:

[image: result of not using AquaLayoutStyle]

And here is the layout you get when using Xcode to lay out a button next to a scrollable component (this is what we should be aiming for if we want Java applications to look native.)

[image: native layout of similar components]

Comment: `LayoutStyle.setInstance(new AquaLayoutStyle());`  Does it work *without* the aqua style?

Comment: Without it, it's worse. You don't get enough spacing between the container and the components, *and* the components still don't line up (the very point of `AquaLayoutStyle` is to fix the layout.)

Comment: I added some more screenshots to show what the default `LayoutStyle` looks like and also what native apps look like.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can't even figure out what you think you're trying to say. The whole point of GroupLayout is to provide a layout manager where when you say things should line up to the left, they will line up to the left. Clearly they are *not* lining up to the left, so I'm asking how to fix that. PLAFs *are* responsible for providing a working `LayoutStyle`, so I don't understand why you seem to think they're not responsible for layout-related issues.